# Claim base approach in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-1.0

We would like to build a permission-based app. Where an admin can set things up such as what a user can or not do.

Say, in Organization-A, an admin can set `User1` to only **CreateTools**, **EditTools** and **ViewTools**. `User2` can only do **CreateTools** and **ViewTools**.

While in Organization-B, an admin here sets `John` to **CreateTools**, **ViewSales** (for some reason, the admin here don't allow `John` to ViewTools)

As you noticed, these are not roles for a user but permissions for every user.

Furthermore, links (anchor tags) on the page will be displayed base on their permissions. Say, `User1` logs in, he can only see links for **CreateTools**, **EditTools** and **ViewTools**

We think that, for us, at least the happy path (Or will this be painful? Please comment on this). Since we'd like to expand this on every organization that would like to use our app and just help them set permissions to their liking.

The way we intend to build this is thru a Web Api (ASP.NET Core) which will be consume by a Client (Browser. A SPA application)

What I've tried before, using ASPNET MVC 5 and have it scaffold with identity and build the app from there. But the thing that was role-base.

I've read about claim-base approach and saw this [blog](https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/03/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-i/) (very helpful) but its not obvious for me on how to implement this using a database and identity. Also read about how JWT works.

For us this is the crucial part but once we get this started on how it works. We'll build the app from there.

Any tutorials, links, blogs. Comments or suggestions will be very helpful. Or terms that we should be researching about.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would look at the open source project `IdentityServer`, the currently released version is version 3, but version 4, hosted in Asp.Net Core, has recently achieved Release Candidate status.

**Architecture Overview**

The `IdentityServer` project would provide you with a `Security Token Service` (STS), which can then be used to provide token based protection to resources, such as MVC pages, Web API calls, mobile applications etc.

`Clients`, `Scopes` and `Claims` define the applications that can use the STS for token based authentication, the type of information that they can request, and the actual Claims (such as users name, email address, etc); these Claims are stored by an `Identity Provider` with a database backend, which is separate from the STS itself.

The STS is tasked with providing implementations of two standards, `OpenID Connect` and `OAuth2`.

[image: Overview presented at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/intro/terminology.html]

The STS will query the `Identity Provider` in order to authenticate a user, and construct a token that can contain Claims related to that user. These tokens are decoded by middleware configured in each `Client`, and the extracted Claims can be utilised to authorize access, optionally in conjunction with [ASP.Net Core Policies](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html), and together this approach will provide you with a comprehensive token and Claim based security architecture.

**Reference material, samples and walkthroughs**

I would strongly suggest you begin by examining the documentation, and samples, for [IdentityServer3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/), and perhaps more specifically [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/).These explain the terminology, and contain comprehensive samples and walkthroughs for implementation.

Dominick Baier, co-author of `IdentityServer`, provides an overview of `OpenID Connect` and `OAuth2` [here](https://vimeo.com/113604459).

Once you understand how token based authentication works, you should move on to examine how to configure an `Identity Provider` that supports your scenario.

There are multiple `Identity Provider` projects available to plug in to `IdentityServer3`, including ASP.Net Identity. Brock Allen (also co-founder of `IdentityServer`) has created the Membership Reboot and Identity Reboot projects for storing Claims etc, and Identity Manager, which provides an administration portal for user management. An explanation of each can be found at the following links:

[Identity Reboot by Brock Allen](https://brockallen.com/2014/02/11/introducing-identityreboot/)

[Introducing Identity Manager by Brock Allen](https://brockallen.com/2014/04/09/introducing-thinktecture-identitymanager/)

[Identity Manager walkthrough by Scott Brady](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity)

`IdentityServer4` currently supports ASP.Net Core Identity, which can, if required, be customised to support multi-tenancy.

A comprehensive set of `IdentityServer4` Quickstarts can be found [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/0_overview.html), including specifically the use of `ASP.Net Core Identity` and `Entity Framework` to store data in `SQL Server` [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html).

Full source code for each of the Quickstarts is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts).

**Authorization Policies**

With regards to authorisation, I recommend [AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop) on GitHub for explanations of various aspects of Claims based authentication and authorisation, specifically including the use of new ASP.Net Core Authorization Policies that can specify fine-grained rules based on Claims, by examining any combination of the set of an individual users Claims to see if they meet the security criteria - and, optionally, traditional Roles, which can also be applied to reduce administration overhead.

**Wrapping Up**

In summary, you could follow the above recommendations to create:

1. A database repository of user Claims, based on ASP.Net Core Identity.
2. A Security Token Service for authenticating the user, and providing
   a token containing the Claims, using IdentityServer.
3. A set of Authorization Policies that evaluate rules against a users
   Claims (and additionally Roles if you choose a hybrid approach).

Security is a complex area, that at first can appear quite daunting. However, both Dominick Baier and Brock Allen are recognised industry experts, who provide a good series of introductions and code samples, and their project, `IdentityServer`, is recommended by Microsoft for claims based authentication.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to share their reasons for doing so. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, this is the first time I've heard about IdentityServer. The way you answer and your knowledge makes us think this is the right path. Will be digging more in-depth unto this one. Thank you so much!

Comment: Bear in mind I have made my preferred suggestion; there are, of course, other solutions, such as Microsoft AD B2C (Active Directory Business to Consumer), which is not yet on General Availability globally, but can be used in North America. That is more of a 'point and click' solution, which may or not may not meet your needs in terms of granularity. Also, Auth0, and other commercial providers offer a hosted service. From evaluating each, and from experience, working with the open source IdentityServer and its strong community gives flexibility; hosting is easy on an Azure App Service.

Comment: Cont: When evaluating the options, factor in cost, feature set, and level of support. In my case IdentityServer was the most flexible and cost effective solution, allowing me to provide a scalable and highly customisable Identity solution without the higher cost of the commercial providers. You really have to make these decisions based on your own scenario and situations...

Comment: I can't really say what's the best solution because the only thing I tried before was the scaffolded ASPNET MVC 5 with Identity but the solution you provide we'll definitely try this one. We'll give this a shot. Tho I haven't gone through all the links you provided but will definitely do so.

Comment: Good luck on your journey - the Quickstarts are really very thorough. I would suggest checking the IdentityServer Gitter channel, and also posting separate, specific questions regarding implementation details here on Stack Overflow, with as much background information as you can.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Is there any way I can contact you just in case I ran into some scenario of identityserver that I do not understand. Or maybe notify you once I start posting question here on SO just to have you two cents :) Because you seem very knowledgeable about IdentityServer and you know what you're talking about.